# Spring boot flyway migrations

Tags: sql, spring-boot, flyway, cockroachdb

I am using flyway for migrations in my Spring boot application. I have around 5 migration scripts with names in the below fashion:

```
V1__initialmigrations.sql
V2__alter_message_table.sql
```

When the migrations run and I see the data in 'flyway_schema_history' table, the data looks good for all migration scripts except the very first one for which under the 'script' column, the value is '<< Flyway Baseline >>' rather than the name of the script unlike other rows. Also, the 'installed_by' column has the value 'null' for this very row while other have the user name that I have in my Spring boot yml file. Also, the 'checksum' is null as well.
The only flyway related properties in the spring env yml file are :

```
spring:
  flyway:
    baseline-on-migrate: true
    enabled: true
```

I am not sure if this is the right behavior. Any inputs would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You only use the `baseline-on-migrate` property if you've created a new baseline after the initial application. Flyway ignores all script with a version below what is set in `baseline-version` (default 1).

For example in applications i've worked on we had years of migration script backlog. we replaced all of them with a single file with current db structure and enabled `baseline-on-migrate` with `baseline-version: X.1` where our new baseline script was `VX_0_0`.

See also official documentation on baseline: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/baselinemigrations

Comment: But that doesn't explain having a nul checksum and installed_by for the baseline.

Comment: The checksum is null as the migration line for BASELINE is not much more than a placeholder. there is no actual SQL that is run to make a checksum for.
the baseline row in migration script is only there to tell flyway not to look at migration scripts with a lower number. otherwise it would throw exceptions that your current migration is at version 5 while it found a unexecuted migration with version 1

Comment: But the create table script in 'V1__initialmigration.sql' does run. I do see the table being created. So, there is a valid script in there. Its more than a placeholder. As I said, its the only script which i dont see in any of the rows, but I can see all other script names mentioned in the subsequent rows under the 'script' column 'flyway_schema_history.

Comment: Also, I went through the link you mentioned. It says all baseline migrations need to start with 'B' and 'baseline migrations do not replace versioned migrations'. I do not have any script that starts with a 'B'. All start with 'V'.